# VBA EXCEL Merging Rows in one Columns

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a column which lists through different modules, with some repeating for 5 rows, some for 20. I am trying to merge these through VBA however something is wrong with my code. Here is the Sub I am using for this, I have commented where the error comes after i debugged it line by line. Would appreciate any input on this error!

Thanks guys!

Notes:

- i starts on 7 as that is the row where the module records start from.

  ```
  Sub ReMergeECURowsMPNT()

  Dim wsMPNT As Worksheet
  Set wsMPNT = Worksheets("Module Part Number Tracker")

  Dim lrowMPNT As Long
  lrowMPNT = CRC.LastRowInMPNT

  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long

  Dim sameRows As Boolean
  sameRows = True

  For i = 7 To lrowMPNT
      If StrComp(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i + 1, 3), vbTextCompare) Then

          sameRows = False

      End If

      If sameRows = False Then
          With wsMPNT
              .Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i + 1, 3)).Merge        '''Application defined error on this line
          End With
      End If

      sameRows = True
  Next i
  ```

  End Sub

Comment: Try qualifying the `Cells` with a dot: `.Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i + 1, 3)).Merge`

Comment: Also, as an aside, I would consider whether you truly need to merge the cells. Just saying, because with Merged cells, if you try to run any sort of math/analysis/vba on it later, it can get a little tricky.  See [this page](http://www.excel-user.com/2012/01/avoid-merged-cells-in-excel.html) or [this one](https://accessanalytic.com.au/stop-merging-cells/) for some examples why.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `DisplayAlerts` is set as `False`, you should typically get a prompt like *"The selection contains multiple data values. Merging into one cell will keep the upper-left most data only."*, and if clicked *"Cancel"* instead of *"Ok"*, VBA will throw an *"Application-defined or object-defined error"*.

Also, check the line `lrowMPNT = CRC.LastRowInMPNT`. If you are looking for merging *"Column C"*, you may try something as simple as this:

```
Sub ReMergeECURowsMPNT()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim wsMPNT As Worksheet, lrowMPNT As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Set wsMPNT = Worksheets("Module Part Number Tracker")
    wsMPNT.Select
    lrowMPNT = wsMPNT.UsedRange.Row - 1 + wsMPNT.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 7 To lrowMPNT
        If Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i + 1, 3) Then
            j = j + 1
        ElseIf j > 0 Then
            Range(Cells(i - j, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Merge
            j = 0
        End If
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```